# Flask-socketio emit in route

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I can`t emit in route. I want to emit when function was called, but it gives error.

Like this`

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('my event')
@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def hello():
    emit('my response', {'data': 'got it!'})
    return "11"
```

Comment: If you emit in an HTTP request you need to specify the `namespace` and the `room`. These are obtained from the context when you reply to an event, but in the HTTP request these are not known, so they need to be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Use `namespace` in flask-socketio to emit in route.

```
@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/hello')
def hello():
    emit('my response', {'data': 'got it!'})
    return "11"
```